# Correct way to protect URL with JSON web token

Tags: node.js, security, cookies, express, jwt

Say I have the following non-api route:

```
app.get('/userprofile', isAuthenticated(), function(request, response) {
    response.render('pages/userprofile');
});
```

What is the correct way to protect that route with a JWT? There will not be an "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" header as the req is coming from the browser, not the client code. But the token will be in the req.cookies.

As I understand it though, reading the token from the cookies opens up the site to CSRF. I don't want to have to rely on server side sessions, as that defeats the purpose of using JWT. Using the expressjs csurf middleware also doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: have the non-api route return non-sensitive html with javascript, and have the javascript access an api route to get the data.

Comment: So JWT are not designed to protect URLs, but rather api endpoints that are accessed from client code?

Comment: api endpoints accessed from anywhere, even other servers. The security vulnerability you are describing is unique to one particular type of client: web browsers, or possibly mobile/desktop apps, but to a lesser degree.

Comment: A CSRF attack in this case could be caused by, for example, a 3rd party browser extension sending an http request for the user to your server. If that token is in a cookie, that's a CSRF attack because you're server won't be able to tell the difference and will perform the action because the cookie will be automagically sent along with the request. Don't store these tokens in cookies.

Comment: Good reading about the subject. https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/

Comment: Thanks @MikaTuupola but that post is what confused me. They recommend storing the JWT in a cookie, but that enables CSRF. It seems you simply cannot protect a URL with a jwt safely, so I will have to take Kevin's suggestion and switch from server-side rendering to client side. I will then add an http interceptor to set the Authorization header on every request.

Comment: To set the Authorization header you still have to store the token somewhere. Protecting against CSRF is fairly easy, but yes, it is an additional step.